# linux newbie-- how to determine the pid for a process corresp. to specific app/web app

Tags: linux, pid

I wish to start a web app in a linux server-- and then monitor its performance periodically using top command.

However top requires the pid (for getting stats of a specific app/process)-- and what I wish to know is, is it possible to obtain the pid programmatically? In such a way, that I login to that server via SSH, run shell commands to determine the PID of that process, and finally run the shell command for top passing that PID as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which programming language ?

try

```
ps -ef | awk '{if ($8 ~ /<nameOfApp>/) print $2;}' > /tmp/tmpFile_
```

you could then read off the PID from tmpFile_ and call

```
top -p <PID>
```

Comment: well the app can be in --> java/php/python/ruby/perl/node.js/.net(mono)